# How can I call Javascript function from Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, api, controller, postman

I am making web/mvc project with Microsoft.AspnetCore.Mvc.Core version 5.0.0.0. When I send a request to the Controller with Postman, I want the javascript function to run without onclick.

In summary, I want to send request from postman to api controller and I want to be aware of view section. I tried with Viewbag in Home Controller but failed.

can i make it? Thanks in advance.

```
[ApiController]
    public  class DevicesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult Focus(int id)
        {
      js function(LoadAndZoom) should work or call when this method works.  
        }

}

//js function 
this is the function i want it to work

function LoadAndZoom(id, tag, mapId, latitude, longitude) {

       
        };
```

postman url: https://localhost:11111/api/example/devices/focus?id=4

Comment: If I don't get you wrong, You want to call an API and call a JS function in a different computer/Browser.
in this case, you can use SignalR

Comment: It doesn't work that way. If you want the server to be able to initiate communication with the client then you need to use websocket tecknology or SignalR.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because this is more of asking if something is possible, not asking how to do something where you've demonstrated you made an effort to actually achieve your goal. Please add more details about what your goal is and give clear and concise examples about what you've tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas.  Company project, I couldn't share these codes any more.  I'm new to software and this was my first question.  I haven't tried solutions like viewbag, scriptmanager but it didn't work.  I will solve it with websocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a controller action from a JavaScript function but not the other way around. How would the server know which client to target? The server simply responds to requests.

Comment: Thanks for commments. I will solve the problem with websocket.